# fatal error: 'libintl.h' file not found in ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

OS: Ubuntu18.04

I am trying to build libusb for android on Ubuntu18.04 following the steps in https://github.com/hutorny/netcat_android. When I reach the step for running `NDK/ndk-build`, I get the error:

```
/home/crue/netcat_android/jni/netcat/src/intl.h:26:10: fatal error: 
      'libintl.h' file not found
#include <libintl.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [/home/crue/netcat_android/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/netcat//home/crue/netcat_android/jni/netcat/src/core.o] Error 1
```

I tried installing the packages `libc6-dev` and `gettext` which according to some sources contain libintl. Then when I run `locate libintl`, I get:

```
/home/crue/libintl_issue
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/libintl.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/preloadable_libintl.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/share/gettext/intl/libintl.rc
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/share/java/libintl.jar
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/preloadable_libintl.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/share/gettext/intl/libintl.rc
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/share/java/libintl.jar
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/39/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/preloadable_libintl.so
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/39/usr/share/gettext/intl/libintl.rc
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/39/usr/share/java/libintl.jar
/usr/include/libintl.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/preloadable_libintl.so
/usr/share/gettext/intl/libintl.rc
/usr/share/java/libintl.jar
```

I also viewed `gcc` include path using `cpp -v` and got:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=cpp
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1 -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

As you can see, I have the `libintl.h` file in the path that gcc uses for includes `/usr/include` but still the error occurs. I would really appreciate help in solving this error.

Comment: it looks like you are listings the base system's include path, not the cross compilation ones.

Comment: I am still a beginner in this so i had no clue about cross compilation. After some reading around it I was able to get rid of the error, because before I was not using any cross compiler. Thanks a lot.